# Speech comparison engine

Tags: javascript, language, speech-recognition, voice-recognition, webassembly

I need a lightweight, non-cloud library to compare speech samples with words (preferrably for English, French, German, Spanish and pther languages), written in JS or WebAssembly or compiled for JS with Emscripten.

For example, it should compare the word "pickle" with a speech sample

Answer (score 0):

You can try [vosk-api](https://github.com/alphacep/vosk-api/issues/49), it works in a browser, supports 7 languages.